# Indexing files in Azure Cognitive Search without indexers?

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

[This article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/tutorial-optimize-indexing-push-api) mentions that it is possible to directly push data to an Azure Cognitive Search index via code, without any indexers or data sources. However the example shown there only accomplishes this for plain objects. My aim is to do this for files(.pdf, .docx, .html). I tried to push a byte array but that didn't work.

I'm aware that it is possible to use indexers to ingest files by pointing them at Azure Blob Storage for example. But I'm trying to avoid indexers altogether. Can this be done? How?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you trying to avoid indexers since they already do exactly what you're trying to do? If you don't want to use indexers, you'll have to do yourself all the work they're doing, including cracking documents open and transforming the data so it corresponds to the index schema.

Comment: @BertrandLeRoy the number of data sources I have to deal with far exceeds the maximum number allowed by any tier. And the highest tier is already unaffordable in my 
particular situation.

Comment: Well, then you'll have to do the work of either cracking the documents open and mapping them to the index schema, or aggregate all your data sources to a single one and then point an indexer at that.

Comment: Hey @BertrandLeRoy thanks for the insight. Maybe we should be coming at this from a different angle. Currently, we’re looking at 200,000+ different data sources with our current levels of data, and that is ever expanding, but each data source is relatively small - 200 to 2500 pdf/word files. Maybe there’s a better way to approach this?

Comment: Sorry, those two approaches are the only possibilities I can see.